# How to change the owner of the current PowerBi dashboard, if the previous employee changed the place of work, but they appointed me instead?

Tags: powerbi

Our company had an employee who authored a report on PowerBi.

Now he has changed his place of work, his account has been deleted, the employee himself is not answering phone calls and the report has stopped working due to the fact that the report cannot receive data.

I was assigned to his place. Can I write somewhere and attach a letter from my boss to make me the author and owner of the report?

I can’t write in support of PowerBi because they ask for confirmation from the administrator and before I can create a ticket, they need to be given access to the corporate repositories, but I would like to solve this without such permissions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is in no way related to programming

Comment: @Exelian I disagree because powerbi is a programming related tool. This like asking a question about an IDE-Configuration.

Comment: Im afraid I feel those questions would be offtopic as well. Especially given the question (permissions without usage of proper channels) I feel that there are more appropriate places to ask this question